# Alteryx: Creating multiple Histograms from one dataset

Tags: histogram, alteryx

I have a data set that contains the following information - Date, item # and the unit price for that item on that date.What I would like to create is one histogram per item (my dataset has 17 unique items), charting the frequency of the unit prices? Is this possible in Alteryx?

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is the ability to group by items within your data set.  I think the closest thing to this for your specific use case is the summarize tool.  You can group by item and then use the percentile operation to generate several points within the data range to add to a histogram.